# Is there a way to pause streambuilder and start it programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, algolia

i have a streambuilder that connects to Algolia for data to bring back to my search page, my issue is that when it finds data it keeps refreshing the results constantly even if the user is not typing,  think this would be annoying for the user, I need It to pause when it finds data and only refresh when the users start typing to give the user time to read through his results

here is my code

```
StreamBuilder < List < AlgoliaObjectSnapshot >> (
    stream: Stream.fromFuture(_operation(_searchTerm)),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Start Typing", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), );
        else {
            List < AlgoliaObjectSnapshot > currSearchStuff = snapshot.data;

            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    else
                        return CustomScrollView(shrinkWrap: true,
                            slivers: < Widget > [
                                SliverList(
                                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                        (context, index) {
                                            return _searchTerm.length > 0 ? DisplaySearchResult(artDes: currSearchStuff[index].data["name"], artistName: currSearchStuff[index].data["price"].toString(), genre: currSearchStuff[index].data["quantity"].toString(), ) :
                                                Container();

                                        },
                                        childCount: currSearchStuff.length ?? 0,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        );


            }
        }


    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stream _yourSteam = Stream.fromFuture(_operation(_searchTerm)),
void pauseStream(){
_yourSteam.listen((event) { }).pause();
}
```

I have never worked with this type of stream, but Test maybe answer

```
StreamBuilder < List < AlgoliaObjectSnapshot >> (
    stream: _yourSteam,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Start Typing", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), );
        else {
            List < AlgoliaObjectSnapshot > currSearchStuff = snapshot.data;

            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    else
                        return CustomScrollView(shrinkWrap: true,
                            slivers: < Widget > [
                                SliverList(
                                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                        (context, index) {
                                            return _searchTerm.length > 0 ? DisplaySearchResult(artDes: currSearchStuff[index].data["name"], artistName: currSearchStuff[index].data["price"].toString(), genre: currSearchStuff[index].data["quantity"].toString(), ) :
                                                Container();

                                        },
                                        childCount: currSearchStuff.length ?? 0,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        );


            }
        }


    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

If algolia presents you results without even typing then, you have to control how results are streamed, even if you are planning on pausing the stream, everything comes through when you resumed it (as stream results are buffered while paused), I would approach it like this

```
class Search{
    bool _shouldEmit = true;

  void pause(){
    _shouldEmit = false;
  }
  void resume (){
    _shouldEmit = true;
  }
  
  Stream<dynamic> searchFor(String searchTerm) async*{
   final results = _operation(searchTerm);//your future operation
   await for(final result in results){
     if(_shouldEmit){
       yield result;
     }
   }
  }
}
```

use it like this

```
final mySearch = Search();
final theStream = mySearch.searchFor("keanu reeves");
///listen to the stream or pause when needed
mySearch.pause();
```

Comment: thanks, let me try this, how do I know when the user is done typing so I could pause the stream and start the stream only when they start typing